# HTTP request Readystate=4 and Status=400

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, api

Im trying to make a POST call on a JSON based API, but im keep getting Status:400, bad request.
Here is my current code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>API TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
      function myFunction() {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              //alert(this.status);
              alert(this.readyState);
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              }
          };
          xhr.open("POST", URL);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
          xhr.send(JSON.stringify({username: "test", password: "test"}))
      }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where the `URL` is defined ???

Comment: As you send user credentials I doubt you can use `get`. Instead try `post`

Comment: My bad. Its suppose to be POST, i just changed it to GET just for trying.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the URL is defined in xhr.open("POST", URL);

Comment: @Omar that is where you access `URL` but you never defined the variable. You might have left it out of the question but it is good to show that it atleast has been defined. If you didn't define the `URL` than that is most likely the problem

Comment: @SuperDJ The URL is indeed defined, i just changed it to "URL" for this post.

Comment: The most important part in your question is this URL variable since response status code 400 indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.

Comment: The URL Im using is correct. Is there anything else that can cause this issue?

Comment: Is this your API you're calling, or a third party one?

Comment: @Alohci its a third party API

Comment: Then it's very likely that your request is not complying with the requirements of that API. Check the documentation for the API, or contact the suppliers of the API for assistance.